# How to run term filter on a field which has child fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: php, json, api, search, elasticsearch

I have a document in my **Elasticsearch** node which contains information about a person's contacts :

```
"contacts": [
      {
         "id": 1,
         "address": "address1",
         "tel": "40071322",
         "doctor_id": 1,
         "type_id": 1,
         "lng": "51.374720",
         "lat": "35.781986",
         "city_id": 186,
         "province_id": 8,
         "hour_about": null,
         "place_name": null
      },
      {
         "id": 2,
         "address": "address2",
         "tel": null,
         "doctor_id": 1,
         "type_id": 2,
         "lng": "51.520313",
         "lat": "35.726983",
         "city_id": 186,
         "province_id": 8,
         "hour_about": null,
         "place_name": null
      },
      {
         "id": 3,
         "address": "address3",
         "tel": null,
         "doctor_id": 1,
         "type_id": 2,
         "lng": "51.456368",
         "lat": "35.797505",
         "city_id": 186,
         "province_id": 8,
         "hour_about": null,
         "place_name": null
      }
]
```

I want to run a `term` **filter** to find documents that have `city_id` of `X` in their `contacts` fields. How should I do this query when the field itself has children fields like above ?

using `elasticsearch php api` is preferred =)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what all have you tried doing till now?

Comment: @Ashesh, I've tried `'term' =>
                            array (
                                'contacts' => intval($value)
                            )`

Comment: @Ashesh, I think I should use `term` filter right? cause its 1 value

Comment: include the mapping you have used. Did you use nested document or parent child for your mapping of contacts. The query will depend on the type of mapping you have used.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without using any plugins.

```
<?php
$jsondata = '{"contacts":[
               {"id":1,"address":"address1","tel":"40071322","doctor_id":1,"type_id":1,"lng":"51.374720","lat":"35.781986","city_id":186,"province_id":8,"hour_about":null,"place_name":null},
               {"id":2,"address":"address2","tel":null,"doctor_id":1,"type_id":2,"lng":"51.520313","lat":"35.726983","city_id":186,"province_id":8,"hour_about":null,"place_name":null},
               {"id":3,"address":"address3","tel":null,"doctor_id":1,"type_id":2,"lng":"51.456368","lat":"35.797505","city_id":186,"province_id":8,"hour_about":null,"place_name":null}
            ]}';
$jsonArray = json_decode($jsondata, true);

echo ('<pre>');
print_r ($jsonArray);
echo ('</pre>');

foreach($jsonArray["contacts"] as $person) {
  if($person['city_id'] == 186) {
    echo "id = " . $person['id'];
    echo "<br/>";
  }
}
?>
```

`$jsondata` stores the JSON, you can also supply it through an

- external file on disk

`$jsondata = file_get_contents ('./contacts.json');`

- url

`$jsondata = file_get_contents ('http://www.example.com/contacts.json');`

`json_decode` decodes the JSON into an Associative array, and it is stored in the variable `$jsonArray`, which is then printed.

comparison is done in the `for` loop, using the `if` statement.

Now in this case since all have same value for `city_id` *(=186)*, all the three corresponding `id` values would get printed.

Demo [here](http://ideone.com/asBGLe).